# Why can't a lock be unlocked by a different thread, while a binary semaphore can?

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, synchronization, locking, semaphore

In terms of the concepts of a lock and a binary semaphore in concurrency programming, why can't a lock be unlocked by a thread which didn't lock the lock, while a binary semaphore can be released/signaled by a thread which didn't acquire/wait it?

Is a binary semaphore a lock? So should my question be a binary semaphore vs a lock which isn't a binary semaphore?

Thanks.

Comment: A binary semaphore is indeed a lock if you play by rules. Why use lock if other thread just enters the critical section before acquiring lock ? Is lock a lock ? A bad implementation doesn't mean it can't be used as a lock. In gerards to you question in the title I find it interesting and have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Because lock (I assume you mean some form of mutex here) and binary semaphore have different semantics and implementation.

Binary semaphore is based on a simple counter primitive to which you can apply atomic increment (***lock inc [counter]***) and decrement (***lock dec [counter]***) operation. Therefore, semaphore does not care about who actually request these operations. It cares only about how to ensure that both will be atomic.

In contrast, mutex implement ownership semantics and is based on atomic CAS operations (***lock cmpxchg [counter], expected_val, new_val***). Therefore, when you want to take a lock, you expect to find some predefined value in mutex variable (usually it is NULL) and write your thread ID in case of success. When you want to release the mutex, then you expect to find yours thread ID in mutex variable, and write NULL into it in case of success. Note! That this stuff is working only because of features of CAS-instruction. It perform in one atomic action three steps:

1. read the value from memory
2. compare the read value with 'expected' argument from register
3. if and only if they are equal, it writes 'new' value from register back to memory.